# Java Generics: On arraylist (unbounded wildcard type), add and addAll methods behaves differently

Tags: java, generics

To be direct here's an example:

```
    ArrayList <?> x = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList y = new ArrayList();
    x.add("abc"); // Clause 1. Compilation error - No problemo. Understood.
    x.addAll(y); // Clause 2. No compilation error
```

For unbounded wildcard, one cannot add. Why there is no compilation error on the last statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are invoking the method with a raw type. The compiler can't perform type checks. If you make `y` user generics, `addAll(..)` will fail.

Comment: Ok. I see the meaning. Clause 1 will fail - since type is known and it follows the general rule where unbounded wildcard prevents addition. Clause 2, since the type element is  unknown, it uses the general rule of  mixing legacy and generic code. Did i get it right?

Comment: yes - in case of raw types, all the generics stuff is discarded.

Comment: @yapkm01 generics where added late to the language so they had to be designed in a way that allowed easy interaction with the large number of existing non generic libraries, as a result the compiler ignores generics in the presence of raw types.